# Assigning a variable to another variable in the current list / file in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook.yml file that reads inventory files, for example service_1.yml and service_2.yml.
I need to reassign the ram_min variable and add some number.

```
playbook.yml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: "Include var"
    set_fact:
      ram_list: "{{ ram_list | default([]) + [ lookup('file',item) | from_yaml ]}}"
    with_items:
      - service_1.yml
      - service_2.yml

  - debug:
      var: ram_list
...
```

---

```
service_1.yml
---
name: service_1
ram_min: 1024
ram_max: "{{ ( ram_min + 256 ) | int }}"
...
```

---

```
service_2.yml
---
name: service_2
ram_min: 2048
ram_max: "{{ ( ram_min + 256 ) | int }}"
...
```

As a result, I get:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "ram_list": [
        {
            "name": "service_1",
            "ram_max": "{{ ( ram_min + 256 ) | int }}",
            "ram_min": 1024
        },
        {
            "name": "service_2",
            "ram_max": "{{ ( ram_min + 256 ) | int }}",
            "ram_min": 2048
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to see:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "ram_list": [
        {
            "name": "service_1",
            "ram_max": 1280,
            "ram_min": 1024
        },
        {
            "name": "service_2",
            "ram_max": 2304,
            "ram_min": 2048
        }
    ]
}
```

Tell me, how can I solve this problem?

PS. I definitely need to import inventory files, I do it through - "lookup ('file' .."

**UPDATE**

```
playbook.yml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: "Include var"
    include_tasks:
      file: include_variables.yml
    with_filetree:
      - "{{ workspace_temp_dir }}"
    when:
      - app_list_temp.state == 'file'
      - app_list_temp.path.split('/')[0] in app | default(app_list_temp.path.split('/')[0])
      - not app_list_temp.path.split('/')[0] is match(exclude) | default([])
      - app_list_temp.path.split('/')[-1] == 'main.yml'
    loop_control:
      loop_var: app_list_temp
...
```

---

```
include_variables.yml
---
- name: "Include variable files to /"
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ app_list_temp.src }}"
- name: "Include variable files to /temp_list"
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ app_list_temp.src }}"
    name: temp_list
- name: "Combine variables to list"
  set_fact:
    app_list_combine: "{{ app_list_combine | default([]) + [ temp_list ] }}"
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that *lookup('file',item)* does not expand the content. *include_vars* is needed. Hence loop of *include_vars* + *set_fact* is needed, but it's not possible to loop a block. IMO only solution is to loop *include_tasks*. The play below

```
- name: "Include var"
  include_tasks: create-ramlist.yml
  loop:
    - service_1.yml
    - service_2.yml
- debug:
    var: ram_list
```

with

```
create-ramlist.yml
---
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
- set_fact:    
    ram_list: "{{ ram_list | default([]) + [ {'name': name,
                                              'ram_max': ram_max,
                                              'ram_min': ram_min} ] }}"
...
```

gives:

```
"ram_list": [
    {
        "name": "service_1", 
        "ram_max": "1280", 
        "ram_min": 1024
    }, 
    {
        "name": "service_2", 
        "ram_max": "2304", 
        "ram_min": 2048
    }
]
```

Comment: +1Thanks for your reply. And if service_1.yml, for example, has additional parameters cpu_max and cpu_min, which are not present in service_2.yml. How then will set_fact be built?
I suggested that so
    ---
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: temp_vat

    - set_fact:    
        ram_list: "{{ ram_list | default([]) + [ item ] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ temp_var }}"
    ...
But it does not work

Comment: Use default filter.

Comment: Added filer, for example - 'cpu_min': cpu_min | default(None). In this case, the variables cpu_min and cpu_max are inherited from service_1.yml
You must somehow clean up all variables before using include_vars.
There is an option with quick cleanup, rather than listing them all in set_fact, for example - set_fact: cpu_min=[] ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any quick cleanup.